# grpc can't find protobuf library

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I went over the grpc installation and finished building and installation.

Now when I try to:

`find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)`

I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake

  but it set gRPC_FOUND to FALSE so package "gRPC" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:
  protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotoc
```

Event though

`find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)`

Works just fine.

I read I'm supposed to run `cmake ../.. -DBUILD_DEPS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` to solve this. However that results in:

```
CMake Error at cmake/abseil-cpp.cmake:38 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "absl" with any of
  the following names:

    abslConfig.cmake
    absl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "absl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "absl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "absl"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:191 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ray/CLionProjects/grpc/grpc/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ray/CLionProjects/grpc/grpc/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Content of /usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake

```
# Module path
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/modules)

# Depend packages






# Targets
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gRPCTargets.cmake)
```

Comment: Could you show content of `/usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake`? It should contain `find_package(Protobuf)` or so, but it is worth to know that for sure.

Comment: I've added it to the desc.

Comment: Well, something has gone wrong and `find_package(Protobuf)` hasn't been added into `gRPCConfig.cmake`. You may try to call `find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)` or `find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)` before the `find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)`. (Additional `find_package` is not a normal way for use `find_package(gRPC)`, but it could help to make it "just working").

Comment: "I went over the grpc installation and finished building and installation." - Are you sure, that exactly your installation is used, and not some other one? In other words, is it your installation which has been installed `/usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake` file? (You may run `make install` from grpc build directory again and see the list of files it writes).

Comment: Thanks, putting find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) into that file actually solved it.

Comment: @user2524707 If you found a working solution, please consider writing up an answer post showing the code changes you made to fix the problem. This will benefit future viewers of your question so they can quickly see a solution.

Comment: Since @Tsyvarev suggestion solved it, I was waiting for him to make the answer so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is actually with the project you use via `find_package()` and with its package file (`/usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake` in your case). The error message

```
The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing:
```

means, that the package file references IMPORTED targets but they are never defined.

The usual reason for that problem is following:

1. During its own build, the project uses `find_package()` for some other packages. This `find_package()` call defines IMPORTED targets, which are used in the project for link.
2. Its package file includes the script(s), which is created by `install(EXPORT)` command and filled according to `install(TARGETS ... EXPORT ...)` command. This included script uses IMPORTED targets, but doesn't define them.
3. The project's package file **forgets** to use `find_package`, or, better, [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) for define the IMPORTED target for the included scripts.

If you don't want to fix the (other) project's package file, then the most direct solution is to add missed `find_package` into your own project:

```
# Hack: This will define IMPORTED targets, needed for gRPC project, but not defined by it.
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
# Now perform the original 'find_package' call.
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

---

Actually, `gRPCConfig.cmake` package file was intended to contain the call `find_package(Protobuf)`. Its template [cmake/gRPCConfig.cmake.in](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/cmake/gRPCConfig.cmake.in) is following:

```
# Module path
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/modules)

# Depend packages
@_gRPC_FIND_ZLIB@
@_gRPC_FIND_PROTOBUF@
@_gRPC_FIND_SSL@
@_gRPC_FIND_CARES@
@_gRPC_FIND_ABSL@

# Targets
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gRPCTargets.cmake)
```

and on substitution the variable `_gRPC_FIND_PROTOBUF` should emit the following code:

```
if(NOT Protobuf_FOUND AND NOT PROTOBUF_FOUND)
  find_package(Protobuf ${gRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE})
endif()
```

(the variable should be set in [cmake/protobuf.cmake](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/cmake/protobuf.cmake)).

But something goes wrong, and the resulted `/usr/lib64/cmake/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake` contains the empty variable's substitution:

```
# Module path
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/modules)

# Depend packages






# Targets
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gRPCTargets.cmake)
```

Comment: Do you want to say it is a bug in grpc's CMake files?

Comment: @LVitya: Yes, it looks like a bug in CMake files generated by grpc project.