# Prebuilding grpc and find_package

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I'd like to link my application with a prebuilt gRPC 1.30.

The directory structure that I want:

```
- project root
  - external
    + gRPC
  - src
    ... my source code here ...
```

I've built gRPC:

```sh
git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.30.0 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
cmake -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="D:/grpc" -A x64 ..
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

The final structure of files produced in `D:/grpc` is weird... the topmost cmake folder contains protobuf-config.cmake and the grpc's one is in D:/grpc/lib/cmake/grpc. But I don't really care as long as it works.

This is in my project's CMakeLists.txt.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY}
    ${EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY}/grpc/ 
    ${EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY}/grpc/cmake/ 
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE grpc::grpc++)
```

And finally, this is the error that I'm getting when I try to build it:

```
  Target "test" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62245040/3440745. That question explains why `gRPC` package requires preliminary `find_package(Protobuf)` call.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```