# Including gRPC and Protobuf libraries using CMake's find_package()

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'd like to include gRPC libraries in my project without specifying them myself.

Something similar to this

[Prebuilding grpc and find_package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562627/prebuilding-grpc-and-find-package)

```
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE grpc::grpc++)
```

Except I would not need to specify the library in the last line

```
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE grpc::grpc++)
```

My aim is to be able to install static gRPC libraries somewhere independently of my project and then link them to it when I provide a path in the command line, such as CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do `find_package` without linking to the package afterwards? And how do you expect not linking to the library to give you the ability to specify the path in the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. The first code snippet is usually the only thing you need. You can provide `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in the command line already with this code, and it will link correctly.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! Yes, I expect to find the package and then call something like `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${gRPC_LIBRARY})`. In the snippet, I have no issue linking `grpc::grpc++`, I'd rather I could have a more general directive.

Comment: Well, I'd say that what you're doing in your snippet is the idiomatic way to link to an external package, wherever it is located. Sending `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `<package-name>_ROOT` through the command line is also okay. I tend to group these parameter in a file I call `dependecies.cmake`  where I make sure to setup the variables to make simply config like your snippet work.

Comment: It does the job to allow me to link specific libraries, that's for sure.

Comment: The way you've done it in your provided CMake code is the preferred, more modular  approach for linking gRPC to your CMake targets. Linking to something like `${GRPC_LIBRARIES}` instead is an older, more antiquated approach, that likely *also* requires you to add the line `target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${GRPC_INCLUDE_DIRS})`, which is less concise.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I am very new to cmake (know and got my app compile with GRPC using make). Could you tell me what I am supposed to point CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to? Is the location of grpc library files or the .pc files or can is just be the directory where all files for grpc are located (like a top level folder).

Comment: @Raaka usually when compiling grpc you'll set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to install the library to a specific location. You have to set the prefix path to the same path as the install path of the library. If you did not installed the library and just copied library files + header and you didn't kept the CMake config files, find package won't work and you'll be expected to manually setting up your targets.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeRacicot, I compiled GRPC a couple of years ago manually, and don't remember (or noticed) any of this earlier! By using `find` and playing around with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` path, I have made some progress and now I am stuck with some cmake-protobuf issue in my project. Thanks for your pointers!